Why SIGSEGV behaves differently from other Exception codes in Android?
I am building an Android application with Native code. I want to handle the exceptions such as SIGSEGV, SIGFPE, SIGILL, etc.
My objective is that in the unlikely scenario that one of them occurs, I am not terminating the application.
Basically, I am following the approach I got from here:

In Application.onCreate, I invoke System.loadLibrary (which invokes JNI_OnLoad)
In JNI_OnLoad, I set the exception handlers (and preserve required global class pointers)
In Activity.onCreate, I store the Activity context and invoke a native method which will create a worker thread.
On the worker thread, I write some bad code that will cause SIGSEGV or SIGFPE.
The exception handler gets triggered on the same worker thread.
In the exception handler, I will invoke an Activity that will shows that something has gone wrong.
Post that I invoke the default exception handler (as recommended). I also kill the worker thread to ensure that the exceptions don't get raised repeatedly.
The process dies due to the invocation of the default handler.
The activity that is started is marked as to be run in its own process (via the manifest file), and hence will not die when the first process dies.

// MainApplication.kt

package com.example.exceptionhandling

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log

class MainApplication : Application ()  {

    override fun onCreate()
    {
        Log.d ("MyApp", "MainApplication.onCreate")

        super.onCreate ()
        System.loadLibrary ("exceptionhandling")
    }

    companion object {

        public var sActivityCtx : Context? = null
    }

}

// MainActivity.kt

package com.example.exceptionhandling

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.example.exceptionhandling.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override
    fun onCreate (pSavedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        Log.d ("MyApp", "MainActivity.onCreate")
        super.onCreate (pSavedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        MainApplication.sActivityCtx = this

        NativeMethod ()
    }

    override
    fun onStop()
    {
        super.onStop()

        Log.d ("MyApp", "MainActivity.onStop")
    }
    
    external fun NativeMethod () : Unit
}


// ExceptionActivity.kt

package com.example.exceptionhandling

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.exceptionhandling.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class ExceptionActivity : AppCompatActivity () {

    companion object {

        // Invoked from C++

        @JvmStatic
        public fun StartExceptionActivity ()
        {
            Log.e ("MyApp", "Inside ExceptionActivity.StartExceptionActivity")

            MainApplication.sActivityCtx!!.startActivity (Intent (MainApplication.sActivityCtx, ExceptionActivity::class.java))
        }
    }

    public override
    fun onCreate (pSavedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        Log.d ("MyApp", "Inside ExceptionActivity.onCreate")

        super.onCreate (pSavedInstanceState)

            val linear_layout : LinearLayout
            val textview      : TextView?

        linear_layout = LinearLayout (this)

        textview = TextView (this)
        textview.text = "Something has gone wrong!!"

        linear_layout.addView (textview)
        setContentView (linear_layout)
    }
}


// native-lib.cpp

#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define TRACE_LOG(x, ...) __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MyApp", x, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define TRACEFUNC TRACE_LOG ("Inside %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
#define TRACELINE TRACE_LOG ("At line: %d", __LINE__)

JavaVM* gJavaVM;
jclass  gExceptionActivityClass; // To store the class pointer of Exception Activity. Will be needed if its methods are to be invoked
thread_local JNIEnv * gThreadLocalEnv;
thread_local bool gIsWorkerThread {}; // Whether the thread is worker thread or main thread

using SignalHandlerFunc = void (*) (int, siginfo_t*, void *);

struct tSignals {

    int uSignal;
    SignalHandlerFunc uSignalHandlerFunc;
    SignalHandlerFunc uDefaultSignalHandlerFunc;
};

void
ExceptionHandler (int pNum, siginfo_t *pInfo, void *pCtx) noexcept;

tSignals gSignals [] =
        {
                {SIGILL,  ExceptionHandler, nullptr},
                {SIGSEGV, ExceptionHandler, nullptr},
                {SIGFPE,  ExceptionHandler, nullptr},
        };

void
ShouldNotGetCalled (int, siginfo_t*, void *) noexcept
{
        TRACEFUNC;

}

SignalHandlerFunc
GetDefaultSignalHandlerFunc (int pSignal) noexcept
{
        TRACEFUNC;

        SignalHandlerFunc func = nullptr;

    for (auto signal : gSignals) {

        if (pSignal == signal.uSignal) {

            func = signal.uDefaultSignalHandlerFunc;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (func)
        return func;

    return ShouldNotGetCalled;
}

void
StartExceptionActivity () noexcept
{
        TRACEFUNC;

        jmethodID  method_id;

    method_id = gThreadLocalEnv->GetStaticMethodID (gExceptionActivityClass, "StartExceptionActivity", "()V");

    if (method_id == NULL) {

        TRACELINE;
        return;
    }

    gThreadLocalEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod (gExceptionActivityClass, method_id);

    TRACELINE;
}

void
AttachThread () noexcept
{
    TRACEFUNC;

    gJavaVM->GetEnv ((void **) &gThreadLocalEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    gJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread (&gThreadLocalEnv, nullptr);
}

void
DetachThread () noexcept
{
        TRACEFUNC;

    gJavaVM->DetachCurrentThread ();
}

[[noreturn]]
void
KillThread () noexcept
{
        TRACEFUNC;

    DetachThread ();

    pthread_exit (nullptr);
}

void
ExceptionHandler (int pNum, siginfo_t* pInfo, void * pCtx) noexcept
{
        TRACEFUNC;

    TRACE_LOG ("Exception number = %d", pNum);

    StartExceptionActivity();

    GetDefaultSignalHandlerFunc (pNum) (pNum, pInfo, pCtx);

    if (gIsWorkerThread)
        KillThread ();
}

void
SetExceptionHandlers () noexcept
{
        TRACEFUNC;

        struct sigaction sa {};
        struct sigaction sa_out {};

    // SIGACTION Register
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESETHAND;

    for (auto & signal : gSignals) {

        sa.sa_sigaction = signal.uSignalHandlerFunc;
        sigaction (signal.uSignal, &sa, &sa_out);

        signal.uDefaultSignalHandlerFunc = sa_out.sa_sigaction;
        TRACE_LOG ("Default handler = %p\n", signal.uDefaultSignalHandlerFunc);
    }

    TRACE_LOG ("ExceptionHandler Set");
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
JNI_OnLoad (JavaVM * pJavaVM, [[maybe_unused]] void * pReserved)
{
        TRACEFUNC;

        jclass exception_activity_class;
        JNIEnv * env;

    gJavaVM = pJavaVM;
    gIsWorkerThread = false;

    if (pJavaVM->GetEnv ((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
        return JNI_ERR;

    exception_activity_class = env->FindClass ("com/example/exceptionhandling/ExceptionActivity");

    if (exception_activity_class == nullptr) {

        TRACELINE;
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    gExceptionActivityClass = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef (exception_activity_class);

    SetExceptionHandlers ();

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void
RaiseException () noexcept
{
        TRACEFUNC;

        int a = 5;
        int b = 0;
        int c;

    c = a / b;

    TRACE_LOG ("Num = %d", c);
}

void *
ThreadFunc (void* ) noexcept
{
        TRACEFUNC;

    gIsWorkerThread = true;

    AttachThread ();

    RaiseException ();

    TRACELINE;

    return nullptr;
}

// Invoked from MainActivity.onCreate

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_exceptionhandling_MainActivity_NativeMethod (JNIEnv* pEnv, jobject pObject)
{
        TRACEFUNC;

    pthread_t thread_handle;

    pthread_create (&thread_handle, nullptr, ThreadFunc, nullptr);
}


In the RaiseException function, I am causing a 'divide by zero' exception, which causes a SIGFPE. The ExceptionHandler gets invoked, which invokes the ExceptionActivity, followed with invoking the default handler, followed withkilling the thread (since its a worker thread).
The ExceptionActivity runs in its own process, and the first process dies out. I get the following logs:
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (4523) for package com.example.exceptionhandling ----------------------------
2024-04-09 20:02:16.117  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  MainApplication.onCreate
2024-04-09 20:02:16.120  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *, void *)
2024-04-09 20:02:16.144  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void SetExceptionHandlers()
2024-04-09 20:02:16.147  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 20:02:16.149  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 20:02:16.149  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 20:02:16.152  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 20:02:16.152  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  ExceptionHandler Set
2024-04-09 20:02:16.807  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  MainActivity.onCreate
2024-04-09 20:02:17.922  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void Java_com_example_exceptionhandling_MainActivity_NativeMethod(JNIEnv *, jobject)
2024-04-09 20:02:17.923  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void CreateThread()
2024-04-09 20:02:17.925  4523-4604  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void *ThreadFunc(void *)
2024-04-09 20:02:17.925  4523-4604  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void AttachThread()
2024-04-09 20:02:17.925  4523-4604  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void RaiseException()
2024-04-09 20:02:17.925  4523-4604  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void ExceptionHandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *)
2024-04-09 20:02:17.925  4523-4604  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Exception number = 8
2024-04-09 20:02:17.925  4523-4604  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void StartExceptionActivity()
2024-04-09 20:02:17.967  4523-4604  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  At line: 46
2024-04-09 20:02:17.967  4523-4604  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside SignalHandlerFunc GetDefaultSignalHandlerFunc(int)
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (4606) for package com.example.exceptionhandling ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (4616) for package com.example.exceptionhandling ----------------------------
2024-04-09 20:02:18.420  4523-4604  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void KillThread()
2024-04-09 20:02:18.420  4523-4604  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void DetachThread()
2024-04-09 20:02:18.580  4606-4606  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  MainApplication.onCreate
2024-04-09 20:02:18.597  4606-4606  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *, void *)
2024-04-09 20:02:18.635  4606-4606  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void SetExceptionHandlers()
2024-04-09 20:02:18.636  4606-4606  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 20:02:18.637  4606-4606  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 20:02:18.637  4606-4606  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 20:02:18.638  4606-4606  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 20:02:18.638  4606-4606  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  ExceptionHandler Set
2024-04-09 20:02:18.825  4523-4523  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  MainActivity.onStop
2024-04-09 20:02:19.181  4606-4606  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside ExceptionActivity.onCreate
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (4616) for package com.example.exceptionhandling ----------------------------


This behavior is as expected. The first process invokes a second process and then the first process dies. Since the second process remains, it does not give a bad experience to the user.
Now if I change the logic of the RaiseException function (that is invoked on the worker thread) to cause a SIGSEGV, things goes for a toss :(
// native-lib.cpp

void
RaiseException () noexcept
{
        TRACEFUNC;

        int * ptr = nullptr;

    *ptr = 45;
    TRACE_LOG ("Num = %d", *ptr);
}

What I've observed is that the ExceptionHandler gets invoked with an exception code of SIGSEGV. Here, I invoke the StartExceptionActivity, which again leads to the ExceptionHandler getting invoked with SIGABRT.
The line that causes that is the CallStaticVoidMethod, which had invoked the StartExceptionActivity in Kotlin. It throws a bunch of exceptions when it attempts startActivity to start the ExceptionActivity. This happens a bunch of times and then everything dies.
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (1678) for package com.example.exceptionhandling ----------------------------
2024-04-09 19:49:49.729  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  MainApplication.onCreate
2024-04-09 19:49:49.731  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *, void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:49.767  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void SetExceptionHandlers()
2024-04-09 19:49:49.767  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:49.767  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:49.767  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:49.768  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:49.775  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  ExceptionHandler Set
2024-04-09 19:49:50.709  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  MainActivity.onCreate
2024-04-09 19:49:51.497  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void Java_com_example_exceptionhandling_MainActivity_NativeMethod(JNIEnv *, jobject)
2024-04-09 19:49:51.497  1678-1678  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void CreateThread()
2024-04-09 19:49:51.499  1678-1758  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void *ThreadFunc(void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:51.499  1678-1758  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void AttachThread()
2024-04-09 19:49:51.499  1678-1758  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void RaiseException()
2024-04-09 19:49:51.499  1678-1758  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void ExceptionHandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:51.499  1678-1758  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Exception number = 11
2024-04-09 19:49:51.499  1678-1758  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void StartExceptionActivity()
2024-04-09 19:49:51.839  1678-1758  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void ExceptionHandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:51.839  1678-1758  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Exception number = 6
2024-04-09 19:49:51.839  1678-1758  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void StartExceptionActivity()
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (1678) for package com.example.exceptionhandling ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (1759) for package com.example.exceptionhandling ----------------------------
2024-04-09 19:49:52.588  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  MainApplication.onCreate
2024-04-09 19:49:52.591  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *, void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:52.603  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void SetExceptionHandlers()
2024-04-09 19:49:52.604  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:52.604  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:52.604  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:52.604  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:52.604  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  ExceptionHandler Set
2024-04-09 19:49:52.967  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  MainActivity.onCreate
2024-04-09 19:49:53.767  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void Java_com_example_exceptionhandling_MainActivity_NativeMethod(JNIEnv *, jobject)
2024-04-09 19:49:53.767  1759-1759  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void CreateThread()
2024-04-09 19:49:53.771  1759-1788  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void *ThreadFunc(void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:53.771  1759-1788  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void AttachThread()
2024-04-09 19:49:53.771  1759-1788  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void RaiseException()
2024-04-09 19:49:53.771  1759-1788  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void ExceptionHandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:53.771  1759-1788  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Exception number = 11
2024-04-09 19:49:53.771  1759-1788  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void StartExceptionActivity()
2024-04-09 19:49:54.110  1759-1788  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void ExceptionHandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:54.110  1759-1788  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Exception number = 6
2024-04-09 19:49:54.110  1759-1788  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void StartExceptionActivity()
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (1759) for package com.example.exceptionhandling ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (1789) for package com.example.exceptionhandling ----------------------------
2024-04-09 19:49:54.911  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  MainApplication.onCreate
2024-04-09 19:49:54.912  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *, void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:54.927  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void SetExceptionHandlers()
2024-04-09 19:49:54.928  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:54.928  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:54.928  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:54.929  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Default handler = 0x7395f2d1ab91
2024-04-09 19:49:54.929  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  ExceptionHandler Set
2024-04-09 19:49:55.585  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  MainActivity.onCreate
2024-04-09 19:49:56.296  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void Java_com_example_exceptionhandling_MainActivity_NativeMethod(JNIEnv *, jobject)
2024-04-09 19:49:56.296  1789-1789  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void CreateThread()
2024-04-09 19:49:56.296  1789-1840  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void *ThreadFunc(void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:56.297  1789-1840  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void AttachThread()
2024-04-09 19:49:56.297  1789-1840  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void RaiseException()
2024-04-09 19:49:56.297  1789-1840  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void ExceptionHandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:56.297  1789-1840  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Exception number = 11
2024-04-09 19:49:56.297  1789-1840  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void StartExceptionActivity()
2024-04-09 19:49:56.783  1789-1840  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void ExceptionHandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *)
2024-04-09 19:49:56.783  1789-1840  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Exception number = 6
2024-04-09 19:49:56.783  1789-1840  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void StartExceptionActivity()
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (1789) for package com.example.exceptionhandling ----------------------------


On opening all the logs, it shows
2024-04-09 19:57:50.419  1928-1956  MyApp                   com.example.exceptionhandling        D  Inside void StartExceptionActivity()
2024-04-09 19:57:50.424  1928-1956  ceptionhandling         com.example.exceptionhandling        A  java_vm_ext.cc:591] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI ERROR (app bug): jobject is an invalid JNI transition frame reference: 0x7395e30c9d20 (use of invalid jobject)
                                                                                                    java_vm_ext.cc:591]     in call to IsInstanceOf
                                                                                                    java_vm_ext.cc:591]     from void android.os.Parcel.nativeMarkForBinder(long, android.os.IBinder)

For some reason, any code I write in Kotlin is causing such errors (even a Log.d).
My questions are:

Why is this happening for only SIGSEGV and not others? Even though the default handlers for them are the same (as seen in the logs).
Is there a way to resolve it?
If no, can I ever handle SIGSEGV?


The only "don't die on seg fault" handler I've ever seen has setjmp/longjump involved.   Basically if you exit the handler via any type of normal control flow, your program will end.  There's nowhere even remotely valid for your program to return to in normal program flow.   I may be wrong, but that's the only thing I've ever seen.

Also, I don't think I've ever seen it in a threaded application.   Not that it's impossible (I don't know), but the use case is actually quite rare to want to continue, as part of your program is fundamentally broken and the ability to disregard that and continue useful things is rare.   segv handlers are usually for diagnostic and clean shutdown purposes, which can be done from the handler.

That's fair.  My only curiosity is that why is SIGSEGV behaving differently from something like SIGFPE.

Just think about the class of situations where a sigfpe is triggered.   It's not difficult to continue a program meaningfully.   But when you've asked for memory that doesn't belong to your process, it's usually unclear where you'd want to go from there.   Whereas a floating point calculation may be expected to fail sometimes and you'd just reject the calculation and move on.

Basically, I am following the approach I got from here:  Ooooof.  That answer is a train wreck of undefined behavior invoked by calling Java code from within a signal handler piled on top of bad ideas like using a cached JNIenv *env.  Get out your brain bleach and wash every last brain cell you have as they have all been infected by looking at that POS.


My objective is that in the unlikely scenario that one of them occurs, I am not terminating the application.

Inside a Java process, you can't do that.
First, JVMs use SIGSEGV internally - which is why it behaves differently - so you pretty much can't install a SIGSEGV handler of your own.  In theory, you could install your SIGSEGV handler if you could differentiate signals that originate from JVM code, where you don't want to interfere with the handling of the signal, from those that originate from code where you do want to interfere with the signal handling.  But in practice that's pretty much impossible to do reliably and it won't address all the other issues with trying to continue running after a supposed-to-be fatal signal.
You can't return from a signal handler for your other signals because the same signal would just be raised again.
So you're left with some version of [sig]setjmp()/[sig]longjmp().
And if you use those, you run the risk of them happening either inside of an async-signal-unsafe function call, or with some state locked by a mutex or some other synchronization object.
If you [sig]longjmp() out of an async-signal-unsafe function, the Linux setjmp() man page explains some of the limitations the entire process must run under:
   POSIX.1-2008 Technical Corrigendum 2 adds longjmp() and
   siglongjmp() to the list of async-signal-safe functions.
   However, the standard recommends avoiding the use of these
   functions from signal handlers and goes on to point out that if
   these functions are called from a signal handler that interrupted
   a call to a non-async-signal-safe function (or some equivalent,
   such as the steps equivalent to exit(3) that occur upon a return
   from the initial call to main()), the behavior is undefined if
   the program subsequently makes a call to a non-async-signal-safe
   function.  The only way of avoiding undefined behavior is to
   ensure one of the following:

   •  After long jumping from the signal handler, the program does
      not call any non-async-signal-safe functions and does not
      return from the initial call to main().

   •  Any signal whose handler performs a long jump must be blocked
      during every call to a non-async-signal-safe function and no
      non-async-signal-safe functions are called after returning
      from the initial call to main().

After you jump out of a signal handler, you will have to restrict the entire process to making only async-signal-safe calls.  Or you have to block your signals prior to every async-signal-unsafe call.  Yet you have no way to ensure the entire JVM will follow either of those restrictions.  In fact, you can effectively be certain the JVM will not work that way.
Note that one of the restrictions is the process can't even return from main() to exit.
And that doesn't even begin to address what happens if you jump out of a context where a mutex is locked, or some other similar situation.
